# bernoulli distribution finding p from standard deviation

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a binomial distribution and my n=20 and I am not give either p or q. I know that the standard deviation is 1/2 and I am asked the value of p.
But after solving the equation of 1/2=sqrt(20p*(1-p)) I have 2 different values of p and I dont know what I should do next to solve this.

Comment: If you did the algebra correctly, both values are solutions.  After all, the standard deviation of a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution and the SD of a Binomial$(n,1-p)$ distribution are always the same.

Comment: While mathematics technically suggests there are two possible answers, if you are in a consulting role, I would bring context into consideration as to what constitutes a rational acceptable solution value for p. Clearly cite and discard what you suspect is an invalid solution in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutuions are merely an interchange of 0 and 1. If the variance is $s^2$, then your solutions are
$$p_{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s^2}{n}}$$
and thus $p_2=1-p_1$.

Comment: And, if you knew, per my comment above, that we are discussing a virus with a very high (or very low) infection rate, are there still two equally 'good'  answers?

Comment: From the original question, it is not clear whether this is a real situation at all. The standard estimator for the variance requires an estimator of the mean to be known, so I do not know whether the problem can actually occur. I wonder whether I shoudl delete my answer, because it answers the question entirely, which is ianapprpriate for homework questions AFAIK.

Comment: @AJKOER In what conceivable consulting engagement would your client know the standard deviation of a Bernoulli variable but not know the mean?

Comment: True, instead a consider a situation where one has a very large sample and one is interested in the method of moments (MOM) non-linear estimator (corrected for bias) for the mean. One already has an idea (per the sample) of the correct size of its expected value, and thus, just employing this information in selecting the correct root as input into the derivation of possibly better/alternate non-linear based estimate (and, yes an MOM estimator can produce an improved estimate as I presented in one of my threads). Also, my answer is very appropriate for a teacher seeking a thought based answer.